# Beam focused through lens at an angle

Tags: optics

Under normal lens operation, a beam is sent through the centre of the lens along the optical axis (ie perpendicular to the lens's plane). What happens when a beam is sent through a lens at an angle to the optical axis? Does it simply exit the lens at the same angle?

Comment: What do you mean by "beam" and "normal circumstances"? An ideal focusing lens passes everything through the focus, regardless of angle. You may want to read more about geometric optics and ray tracing, and that will probably answer your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was asking specifically about a collimated, Gaussian beam. If it's sent along the optical axis, I understand that it will be focused down to a new waist on the optical axis. I guess, I'm more interested in whether or not the beam is deflected at all if it enters the lens at an angle to the optical axis.

Comment: In the thin lens approximation, each of the rays from my picture below can be thought of a collimated beam. The rules for ray tracing would apply. If the thin lens approximation is violated, I'd image there could be significant distortion of the beam due to the geometric effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some rules about what happens to light rays passing through lenses, which are derived from Snell's laws. In short:

a) A ray passing through the focal point into the lens will exit the lens parallel to the optical axis.

b) A ray passing straight into the center of the lens (at any angle with respect to the optical axis) will exit at the same angle.

c) A ray entering the lens parallel to the optical axis will exit the lens and pass through the focal point.

These are standard in any intro physics text, but what the heck I'll draw a simple diagram:

[image]

The object is on the left, I've labeled the three rays appropriately, and the image is on the right (focal points are dots). As you can see, the rays a) and b) are incident with the lens at an angle with respect to the optical axis, which should answer your question.

The same rules apply for concave lenses as well, and also curved mirrors if you make the appropriate adjustments.